# Calling clGetPlatformInfo with CL_PLATFORM_ICD_SUFFIX_KHR in OpenCL 2.1

Tags: opencl

According to the Khronos OpenCL SDK 2.1 online documentation, [clGetPlatformInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformInfo.html) can be called with `CL_PLATFORM_ICD_SUFFIX_KHR` to identify extension functions from the ICD Loader when the [cl_khr_icd](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_icd.html) extension is enabled.

However, `CL_PLATFORM_ICD_SUFFIX_KHR` is not defined in the `cl.h` file supplied with the `Intel OpenCL SDK` nor is it in the [OpenCL 2.1 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-2.1.pdf).

Is this simply an error in the Khronos OpenCL SDK 2.1 online documentation for `clGetPlatformInfo`, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CL_PLATFORM_ICD_SUFFIX_KHR` should be defined in [CL/cl_ext.h](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Headers/blob/03490c3f8cb3b8667942b084a3151de20649f57a/CL/cl_ext.h#L107).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and it is defined in the Intel sdk `cl_ext.h` file.